# SQL Server : WHERE argument

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a SQL statement where I want to filter out the year and the place. The problem is that when I type a year, all the data for this year is being displayed, which is fine but when I input the place it lists places from another year too.

I know that it is so because of the `or` but what do I have to write instead to get my desired result?

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter
(@"select a.FALL, m.CODE, m.ANZ, m.TDAT 
   from lst_test m with (nolock)
   inner join test2 a with (nolock) on a.aid = m.aid 
   where year(m.TDAT) = @jahr or m.Einrichtung=  @einricht  
   order by a.FALL", 
 "Server = sds; Database = dds;Trusted_Connection = True");
```

**EDIT:**

```
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select a.ISH_FALLZAHL, m.ML_CODE, m.ML_ANZ, m.ML_LSTDAT From lst_mdmel_lis_tab m with (nolock) inner join lst_absae_tab a with (nolock) on a.aid = m.aid where (@jahr IS NULL OR YEAR(m.ML_LSTDAT) = @jahr)  and (@einricht IS NULL OR m.L_ANSTALT  = @einricht) order by a.ISH_FALLZAHL", "Server = igvproli19; Database = ADM;Trusted_Connection = True");

        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jahr", textBox1.Text);
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@einricht", textBox2.Text);
        ds = new DataTable(" ");
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

Comment: So you want to filter by year or place or both - given which argument is provided?

Comment: I want to to filter both but i can also Input year without the place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where 
    (@jahr IS NULL OR YEAR(m.TDAT) = @jahr) 
    and (@einricht IS NULL OR m.Einrichtung = @einricht)
```

Change these two lines:

```
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jahr", textBox1.Text);
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@einricht", textBox2.Text);
```

to:

```
if (textBox1.Text == null || textBox1.Text == "")
{
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jahr", DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jahr", textBox1.Text);
}
if (textBox2.Text == null || textBox2.Text == "")
{
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@einricht", DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@einricht", textBox2.Text);
}
```

Comment: Also only works when bot are be inputed. I want it also works when one empty is.

Comment: No. It will work if both are input and when either both are null or one of them is null.  It is important to use null, not empty string, otherwise you must change the OR inside each bracket.  I have used this construction often.  Did you really try it?

Comment: yes i try it at is still not work also when i insert a null

Comment: When @jahr is null, you need to pass the value as DBNull.Value, eg.             adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jahr", DBNull.Value);  Are you doing this?  You have not shown your full code.

Comment: No it Looks so :             adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jahr", textBox1.Text);

Comment: Then you need to surround it with an if statement - if (textBox1.Text == null || textBox1.Text == "")  do my code, else do yours.  Same applies to the second parameter.

Comment: Please note that sending an empty string to SQL Server as a date parameter, will be interpreted by SQL-Server as 1st January 1900!!!

Comment: is still not working it only Display the data when place and year are inserted otherwise nothing been displayed

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AND` rather than `OR`. By using `AND` means that it will show the results which have the YEAR and PLACE the same with your parameter. If you are using `OR`, it means that it will show you the results that having the year OR the place the same with your parameter.

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter
("select a.FALL, m.CODE, m.ANZ, m.TDAT From lst_test m with (nolock)
inner join test2 a with (nolock) on a.aid = m.aid 
where  year(m.TDAT) = @jahr AND m.Einrichtung=  @einricht  
order by a.FALL", "Server = sds; Database = dds;Trusted_Connection = True");
```

**EDIT**

If you are not sure which parameter is given, you could check whether that parameter is null or not, then proceed with the sql.

for example

```
public void ReadDataFromDB(string Year, string Place)
{
    string sql = @"select a.FALL, m.CODE, m.ANZ, m.TDAT From lst_test m with (nolock)
inner join test2 a with (nolock) on a.aid = m.aid 
where 1=1 ";

    if (Year != null && Year.Length > 0)
    {
        sql += "AND year(m.TDAT) = @jahr ";
    }
    if (Place != null && Place.Length > 0)
    {
        sql += "AND m.Einrichtung=  @einricht  ";
    }
    sql += "order by a.FALL";
    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, "Server = sds; Database = dds;Trusted_Connection = True");
}
```

If you are afraid of SQL injection detection system like @Dovydas Sopa said, then you have to check it 1 by 1 then decide which Where clause should be put.

```
public void ReadDataFromDB(string Year, string Place)
{
    string sql = @"select a.FALL, m.CODE, m.ANZ, m.TDAT From lst_test m with (nolock)
inner join test2 a with (nolock) on a.aid = m.aid ";

    if (Year != null && Place != null)
    {
      sql += "Where year(m.TDAT) = @jahr AND m.Einrichtung=  @einricht ";
    }
    else if (Year != null && Place == null)
    {
      sql += "Where year(m.TDAT) = @jahr ";
    }
    else if (Place != null && Year == null)
    {
      sql += "Where m.Einrichtung=  @einricht ";
    }
    sql += "order by a.FALL";
    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, "Server = sds; Database = dds;Trusted_Connection = True");
}
```

Comment: When I use and i have to Input place and year but sometimes i Need only year or only place

Comment: I would avoid adding `1=1` case. If there is any SQL injection detection system it might suspect this query as potential SQL injection risk.

Comment: @myworld please let us see ur code. no way this is not working. maybe u implement it wrong

Answer (score 0):

To search by more than one filter you have to use `AND` instead of `OR` but to filter by year if no place is provided I think something like this should work:

```
where  (year(m.TDAT) = @jahr AND m.Einrichtung=  @einricht) OR
       (year(m.TDAT) = @jahr AND @einricht IS NULL) OR 
       (@jahr IS NULL AND m.Einrichtung=  @einricht)
```

Comment: it was only a example it should work also the other way around. For example i Input place but no year

Comment: In that case you can add another OR statement with the correct conditions. I have updated my answer

Comment: it ist only works when both are inputed do not know why

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both arguments are provided, you can write as following:

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter
 ("select a.FALL, m.CODE, m.ANZ, m.TDAT From lst_test m with (nolock)
 inner join test2 a with (nolock) on a.aid = m.aid 
 where  year(m.TDAT) = @jahr or (m.Einrichtung=  @einricht and year(m.TDAT)=@jahr)   
 order by a.FALL", "Server = sds; Database = dds;Trusted_Connection = True");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you might have place, year or both, then the best way would be to have 3 separate where clauses for each of those cases, f. e.

```
var year = ""; // Set value.
var place = ""; // Set value.
var whereClause = "where " + year != null && place != null ?
    "year(m.TDAT) = @jahr AND m.Einrichtung = @einricht" : year != null ?
    "year(m.TDAT) = @jahr" :
    "m.Einrichtung = @einricht";

adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
    "select a.FALL, m.CODE, m.ANZ, m.TDAT From lst_test m with (nolock)
    inner join test2 a with (nolock) on a.aid = m.aid " + whereClause +
    " order by a.FALL", "Server = sds; Database = dds;Trusted_Connection = True");
```

Also, depending on whether you want to accept empty `string`s or not you can change `!= null` comparison with `string.IsNullOrEmpty` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` methods.